# Yii2 pjax search save param

Tags: yii2, pjax

I have some filter per-page and gridview.
They placed in pjax.
When i change some pagination and sort and after that use my per-page filter - params from pagination and sort are lost.
I want to save it. How to do that?
My code:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax']) ?>
<?= Html::dropDownList('per-page', Yii::$app->request->get('per-page') != NULL ? Yii::$app->request->get('per-page') : [10 => 10], [1 => 1, 5 => 5, 10 => 10, 25 => 25, 50 => 50, 100 => 100], [
    'onchange' => '
        $.pjax.reload({
            url: "'.Url::to([Yii::$app->controller->action->id, 'id' => Yii::$app->request->get('id')]).'?StandartSearch%5Bdate%5D=" + $(\'#date\').val() + "&per-page=" + $(this).val(),
            container: "#pjax",
        });
    ', 
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'id' => 'per-page'
]) ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'gridview',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // columns
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per-page filter are placed within pjax container. So obviously they will get lost when pjax event is completed.

To make them not to lost their current selection, you can place per page filter in the form outside pjax.

and $formSelector property on pjax which points to that filter form id.

reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$formSelector-detail

Comment: Can u give me some example? `<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax', 'formSelector' => '#per-page select']) ?><?= Html::beginForm(['user/index'], 'get', ['data-pjax' => '', 'id' => 'per-page']); ?><?= Html::dropDownList('per-page', Yii::$app->request->get('per-page') != NULL ? Yii::$app->request->get('per-page') : [10 => 10], [1 => 1, 5 => 5, 10 => 10, 25 => 25, 50 => 50, 100 => 100], ['class' => 'form-control']) ?><?= Html::submitButton('Ok', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'name' => 'hash-button']) ?><?= Html::endForm() ?>` This do not works

Comment: <form id="form1">your filter fields here</form>
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax', 'formSelector' => '#form1']) ?>

So whatever is selected from the form will be passed to your action controller as GET parameter. You can grab their values using Yii2::$app->request->get('parametername') and add to where clause of your model query.

Comment: i place my filter in form outsite pjax and set formSelector. Filter work with pjax, but still lost current selection

Comment: there must be some ajaxStop event which makes filter loss their selections. Yii2 by default doesn't do this.

Comment: check this in clean yii2. Filters outsite pjax reset sort. Native filters in gridview save sort. Thx for help.